# Distribution estimation from interval times

Tags: estimators, censoring

In Formula 1 races, an interval time is the lag behind the leader at a split. If first place completes the first lap at 1:30, second place completes the first lap at 1:32, and third place completes the first lap at 1:33, then the interval for second place would be +2s, and the interval for third place would be +3s. First place trivially has an interval of +0s.

Let's say the same 10 racers compete on the same track many times, and you have interval times for the first lap of each race, but not the lap time. That is, if racer $i$ has lap time $X_{i}$, you observe
$$ X_{i} - \min_{1 \leq j \leq 10}X_{j}$$
for every $i$. For simplicity, let's say the $X_{i}$ are iid. The data looks like this:

```
     Racer_1  Racer_2  ...  Racer_9  Racer_10
0        1.3      1.8  ...        0       1.6
1        0.2        0  ...      0.8       1.8

...

N          0      1.3  ...      1.2       0.3
```

We can see that Racer 9 lead in the first sample, and that Racer 2 lead in the second sample. Importantly, the interval time is the delay past the first place leader, not the delay past the next car in front, so from this data we know which racer came in second, which came in third, etc.

**The question is**: how can I construct an estimator for the distribution of $X_{i}$? The data can't detect a constant shift in all of them, so artificially impose, for example, that the true minimum of the distribution of $X_{i}$ is 0.

Some motivation: If instead of 10 racers there were a billion, then min would be very close to the minimum of the distribution of $X_{i}$, and each observation is $X_{i}$ minus that minimum. In that case the empirical distribution is very close to the true distribution shifted so that its support begins at 0.

However, with a limited number of racers, observations are sort of censored by $\min X_{j}$ being larger than the minimum of the distribution. The empirical distribution will be comprised of two parts: a continuous component, and an atom at 0 of censored observations where $X_{i} = \min_{j} X_{j}$.

Concrete example where the underlying distribution is uniform(0,1):
[image: Histogram of empirical distribution]

Code to generate data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(100000,10))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
cols = df.columns
df['min'] = df.min(axis=1)
for col in cols:
    df[col] -= df['min']
df = df.drop(columns=['min'])
df[0].hist(bins=50)
```

Comment: This would seem impossible unless you also had data about which place each interval time is associated with.  In that case, why not use the usual estimator, the arithmetic mean?

Comment: I added some motivation to the question, which might clarify the goal.

Comment: It still doesn't help us understand what data you actually have.

Comment: Ah I see, I've edited the question again to clarify.